# Is there a legal depth limit for scuba divers in Turkey?

Tags: legal, safety, turkey, diving

Last year (2014), the guys from our dive center in Turkey told us that there is a (new) *legal* depth limit of 30m (100ft) for all scuba divers (including CMAS 3* and PADI Dive Master) which is enforced by the coast guards. The only exceptions seem to be training dives.

Is it true that there is (was?) this kind of limit, or did they just pretend it to prevent us from diving deeper?

Note: I do *not* care about limits by diving organisations (PADI/CMAS/...) or insurances.

Answer (score 3):

[According to this site indeed scuba diving in Turkey is heavily regulated.](http://www.wannadive.net/spot/Middle_East/Turkey/) There's an organisation called [TSSF](http://www.tssf.gov.tr) which defines rules and regulations for scuba diving. According to the linked site, the limit for > 18yo CMAS 2* and above is indeed 30m:

> Here a short summary of what is of interest for everybody.
>
> 1. Foreigners are not allowed to dive in Turkey without a licensed Turkish Guide Diver.
> 2. Maximum depth limit for OWD/CMAS* - 18m and they have to be accompanied by a Divemaster/CMAS*** in minimum.
> 3. Maximum depth limit for AOWD/CMAS** and higher – 30m. If they are below 18 years their maximum depth is 24m and only if they are accompanied by a Divemaster/CMAS*** in minimum.
> 4. Scuba Diving is not allowed for minors below the age of 14.

Comment: The linked site does not give a source. On the [TSSF's homepage](http://www.tssf.gov.tr/EN/home) I cannot find this kind of information. Do you have an idea where to look on their page?

Comment: @Scz The linked site mentions where to look on the tssf site, but those paths I could not find. I did find a document in Turkish which contains some mention of a 30m limit. I don't know what it's actually about though. http://tssf.gov.tr/uploads/files/2014_186_donanimli_dalis_talimati__sgm..doc