# Is there a legal depth limit for scuba divers in Egypt?

Tags: legal, diving, egypt

I have been to Egypt for a few times since about 2005.
Many of the diving centers told us there is a *legal* depth limit of **30m** (100ft) for all scuba divers (including CMAS 3* and PADI Dive Master).
However, I found a [document](http://www.projectoceanvision.com/articles/red_sea_rules/depth_limits.pdf) by "CWDS" (Chamber of Diving & Watersports) which says

> The maximum depth for diving with compressed air is 40 meters (if the training
>   qualifications and the experience of the divers allow it)

What is the CWDS? Do the rules from the document apply (i.e., the dive centers just pretend the 30 meter limit to prevent us from diving deeper)
or is it true that there is this kind of limit? (Or is it even allowed to go deeper than 40 meters with a single tank of air?)

Note: I do *neither* care about limits by diving organisations (PADI/CMAS/...) or insurances, *nor* about limits by using Nitrox (which is free in most centers).

**Clarification**: This question is about **Egypt**, whereas my [other question is about Turkey](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/51384/31974). Therefore this is *not* a duplicate.

Comment: I asked it to my Dive master. He answer me: Under water doesn't have police :)

Comment: @JoErNanO 1. As long as Egypt and Turkey are not the same country, this is no duplicate. 2. The question is not even "exactly" the same, if you read it carefully.

Comment: @Afetter Thats right :) But you have to use a diving computer (which saves your maximum depth) and they could control it after the dive.

Comment: Scz - asking the same question for each country in the world would give you a lot of questions I would categorise as all duplicates. How about just slightly changing the wording of your Turkey post to take into account different countries?

Comment: @RoryAlsop that's a point. But wouldn't that question get too broad and the answers too huge? Personally, I'm mostly interested in those 2 countries, as most other countries seem to accept the 40m limits that are common among international diving organisations.

Comment: How would the government be able to enforce such a rule? It's similar to laws prohibiting suicide.

Comment: @JonathanReez For example, they could charge a penalty payment after checking the diving computer. Or hold you responsible if an accident happens at that dive (even if the accident does not have anything to do with the depth, e.g. your buddy gets bitten by a shark in a shallow region at the end of the dive. Enforcing rules does not always make sense)

Comment: @Scz You are right. I wasn't fully awake. :)

Comment: @Scz Regardless of depth you are always responsible for your diving accidents since before letting you on the boat the diving club makes you sign a responsibility waiver. Having said this to my knowledge the only county that allows diving to >40m on a normoxic mix is France, country in which diving is regulated by the law rather than by the federations.

Comment: @Afetter Actually there is police underwater. And in the countries where police actually checks divers they tend to be *way* more and better equipped than you and your dive buddy. I've had freedivers of the French Gendarmerie come visit me at -30m and then wait for us to emerge to check certifications. I've had the divers from the Italian Navy special forces, fully armed and with closed-loop systems, come check us in a marine reserve. Egypt might be different of course but always beware of people claiming that there's no control in or under the water.

Comment: You visited dive centers, which are staffed by experts in the field of diving, for the country in which you visited them, and they told you there is a legal limit; so of course you come to a travel Q&A site to ask if there is a legal limit. This makes no sense. If you went to several motorcycle shops, and they told you driving without a helmet is illegal, you would come here and ask us if it were? Go back to one of the dive shops, or call them, and _ask them to specify the law_. I _guarantee_ that if it _is_ a law, they'll be able to reference it immediately.

Comment: @CGCampbell There are dive centers that say "It's *not* a law". You *won't* find a motorcycle shop where they say its *not* a law. However, I will ask next time when I'm there ;-)

Answer (score 2):

### What's the CDWS?

The Chamber of Diving and Water Sports is a govermental organisation funded in 2007 by the Egyptian Mynistry of Tourism, whose purpose is to regulate all diving and water sports activities in the country. Quoting from [the CDWS About Us webpage](http://www.cdws.travel/about-us):

> The Chamber of Diving and Watersports was founded by Egypt’s Ministry of Tourism in 2007 with a goal to improve quality, safety and standard of services in the diving and watersports industry, as well as to preserve unique environment of the Red Sea.

Indeed, [the Egypt Tourist Authority states that the CDWS regulates all the diving centres in Egypt](http://www.egypt.travel/mobile/page/index/diving-info) (emphasis mine):

> All certified diving centres and schools in Egypt provide all levels of diving trainings [...]. **Their activity is regulated by the official Chamber of Diving and Water Sports (CDWS)** and they all own the EUF (European Underwater Federation) international certification.

### What Does the CDWS Say?

In may 2009 [the CDWS published a file (link in pdf) stating the depth regulation for scuba divers.](http://www.cdws.travel/documents/rules-regulations/CDWS%20policy%20-%20depths%20V6%209%20May%2009.pdf) It states that:

> #### As for the maximum depths for recreational diving:
>
> - CDWS is implementing the World Recreational Scuba Training Council (WRSTC)
>     standards www.wrstc.com for recreational diving.
> - The maximum depth for diving with compressed air is 40 meters (if the training qualifications and the experience of the divers allow it)
> - For Enriched Air diving; the maximum depth is up to a partial pressure of Oxygen (PPO2) = 1.4 ATA (maximum depth 40 meters on single tank)
>
> #### Depth limitations for different activities:
>
> - For Advanced Enriched Air the maximum depth is: 40 meters
> - For Decompression procedures dives (Or equivalent) the maximum depth is: 45 meters
> - For Extended Range dives (or equivalent) the maximum depth is: 55 meters
> - For Normoxic (or entry level) Trimix the maximum depth is: 60 meters
> - For Hypoxic (or advanced) Trimix the maximum depth is: 100meters

It would therefore seem that the diving limit for compressed normoxic air mix is 40m.